# Is there any other library function for xmpp apart from asmack for Android App?

Tags: android, xmpp, instant-messaging

I am trying to develop a **chat application in android using XMPP**. Some search and all I found that I need to use asmack library for my app. It seems little bit old . So I am asking to you all that **is there any other libraries or methods to implememnt IM using XMPP in android apart from asmack ?** And any one please tell me how WhatsApp and Telegram implemnting this ? If they are using XMPP please tell me which library function they are using ? Feel free to ask if you need more clarification regarding the question.